# How to set cookie without response in Django or DRF?

Tags: django, cookies, django-rest-framework, django-views, httpresponse

I tried this `response = Response()` method but it is not set in the browser cookie
Because my function return user and token instead of `response`.Any possibility to set cookie in browser without response or `httpResponse`?..

**views.py(It does not work):**

```
     def authenticate(self, request):
            ......
            new_access_token = result.get('access')
            
            response = Response()
            response.set_signed_cookie(
                       key = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_ACCESS'], 
                       value = new_access_token,
                       salt = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SALT'],
                       expires = 214748364,
                       secure = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE'],
                       httponly = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY'],
                       samesite = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SAMESITE']
                       )
                        
        return self.get_user(validated_token),validated_token
```

**-- Full View.py(above is short) --**

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
from rest_framework_simplejwt.exceptions import InvalidToken
from django.conf import settings
import requests
import json
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .utility import set_browser_cookie

class CustomAuthentication(JWTAuthentication):
    
    def authenticate(self, request):
        header = self.get_header(request)        
        if header is None:
            raw_token = request.get_signed_cookie(settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_ACCESS'],salt = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SALT'],default = False) or None
        else:
            raw_token = self.get_raw_token(header)
        if raw_token is None:
            return None  
        
              
        try:
            validated_token = self.get_validated_token(raw_token)
        except InvalidToken:
            refresh = request.get_signed_cookie(settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_REFRESH'],salt = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SALT'],default = False)
            if refresh is None:
                return None            
                          
            protocol = 'https' if request.is_secure() else 'http'
            domain_name = settings.SITE_DOMAIN_NAME
            url = f'{protocol}://{domain_name}/auth/api/token/refresh/'
            data = {"refresh": refresh}

            resp = requests.post(
                url, 
                data=json.dumps(data),
                headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
                )
            result = resp.json()
            new_access_token = result.get('access')
            
            if new_access_token is None:
                return None
            
            validated_token = self.get_validated_token(new_access_token)
            
            response = Response()
            response.set_signed_cookie(
                       key = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_ACCESS'], 
                       value = new_access_token,
                       salt = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SALT'],
                       expires = 214748364,
                       secure = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE'],
                       httponly = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY'],
                       samesite = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SAMESITE']
                       )
                        
        return self.get_user(validated_token),validated_token
```

### Please help me I am very confuse for this.

Comment: Can you get `new_access_token` from `validated_token`?

Comment: Yes it works perfectly but this new access token does not set in cookie.

Comment: I would override the view that handles the login bit and insert the cookie there.

Comment: My login view is work and set cookie perfectly there but when access token is expired at that time this condition run..tnx @schilinght to reply my question.And sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @schillingt see full view above..I edited.

Comment: Don't try to do the refresh within the authenticate function. It's the calling client's responsibility to refresh the token.

Comment: Thank you so much sir..My 1st confusion is over.My last question is that : If I set refresh token with`httponly=false` is safe or not. For this confusion I tried to get the new access token from the server side by using refresh token.